# ¿ Como hacer para ver la cuenta atrás?

Tags: javascript

Hola estoy haciendo una prueba, al activar la cuenta atrás aparece una ventana con el contador y cuando termine desaparece la ventana.
Pero lo que no consigo es ver la cuenta atrás, como pasan los segundos hasta llegar a cero. El paso de los segundos si lo conseguí con setTimeout, pero la cuenta atrás se me resiste. Llevo varias pruebas sin éxito, por lo que recurro aquí por si me dan idea de como hacerlo.
Me da error el elemento `element.textContent =`Dura ${count} segundos`` Funcionaba hasta añadir este fragmento
Gracias.

```js
        let count = 5
        let myCaja = document.getElementById('caja'); 
        let boton = document.getElementById('button'); 
        let exit = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];
        boton.onclick = function () {
            count --
            element.textContent = `Dura ${count} segundos`
            myCaja.style.display = 'block';
            const timeout = setTimeout(() => { exit.onclick() }, 5000)
        }
        exit.onclick = function () {
            myCaja.style.display = 'none';
        }
        window.onclick = function (event) {
            if (event.target == myCaja) {
                myCaja.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
```

```css
        .myCaja {
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 1;
            padding-top: 100px;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: auto;
            background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        }

        .myCaja-content {
            background-color: #27C504;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #888;
            width: 40%;
        }

        .close {
            color: #aaaaaa;
            float: right;
            font-size: 28px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .close:hover,
        .close:focus {
            color: #000;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title>Probando setTimeout </title>
 </head>

<body>
    <h2>Abrimos la pestaña y cuando termine la cuenta atras...</h2>
    <button id='button'>Enpieza cuenta atras...</button>
    <div id='caja' class='myCaja'>

        <div class='myCaja-content'>
            <span class='close'>&times;</span>
            <p>Dura 5 segundos...</p>
        </div>

    </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es el problema el usar [template String](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) en su código , el problema es que no veo referenciado la variable `elemento` , que supongo que debería el  párrafo `p` , además no veo el interval para simular el conteo regresivo descendente.

Estos detalles se añaden y funcionará correctamente , además si desea que el conteo siempre inicie en 5 deberá declarar la variable a nivel de función o `setear` al cerrar la modal *(para este ejemplo uso la primera opción)* . *(ejm)*

```js
let myCaja = document.getElementById('caja'); 
let boton = document.getElementById('button'); 
let exit = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];
let element = document.querySelector('.myCaja-content p');
boton.onclick = function () { 
 let count = 5 // iniciar siempre en 5
 // Evitar demora al cargar modal básica
 element.textContent = `Dura ${count--} segundos`;
 myCaja.style.display = 'block';
 let interval = setInterval(function(){
  if(count===0) clearInterval(interval);
     element.textContent = `Dura ${count} segundos`;
     count--;
 },1000);
 //limpiamos el text del parrafo
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => { element.innerHTML = ""; exit.onclick()  }, 5000)
}
exit.onclick = function () {
    myCaja.style.display = 'none';
}
window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (event.target == myCaja) {
        myCaja.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```css
.myCaja {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.myCaja-content {
    background-color: #27C504;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 40%;
}

.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h2>Abrimos la pestaña y cuando termine la cuenta atras...</h2>
<button id='button'>Enpieza cuenta atras...</button>
<div id='caja' class='myCaja'>

 <div class='myCaja-content'>
  <span class='close'>&times;</span>
  <p></p>
 </div>

</div>
```

Sí desea hacer funcionar el botón `close` de la modal y cerrar cuando se de `click` fuera de esta , deberá declarar los `interval` y los `timeOut` fuera para poder limpiar el `interval` y `timeout` definido , este proceso lo extraemos a una función para reutilizarla.

```js
let myCaja = document.getElementById('caja'); 
let boton = document.getElementById('button'); 
let exit = document.querySelector('.myCaja-content .close');
let element = document.querySelector('.myCaja-content p');
var interval ;
var timeout ;

boton.onclick = function () { 
 let count = 5;
 // Evitar demora al cargar modal básica
 element.textContent = `Dura ${count--} segundos`;
 myCaja.style.display = 'block';
 interval = setInterval(function(){
  if(count===0) clearInterval(interval);
     element.textContent = `Dura ${count} segundos`;
     count--;
 },1000);
    timeout  = setTimeout(() => {  exit.onclick()  }, 5000)
}
exit.onclick = reset;
window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (event.target == myCaja) {
        myCaja.style.display = 'none';
        reset();
    }
}

function reset(){
 element.innerHTML = "";
 clearInterval(interval);
 clearTimeout(timeout)
    myCaja.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
.myCaja {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.myCaja-content {
    background-color: #27C504;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 40%;
}

.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h2>Abrimos la pestaña y cuando termine la cuenta atras...</h2>
<button id='button'>Enpieza cuenta atras...</button>
<div id='caja' class='myCaja'>

 <div class='myCaja-content'>
  <span class='close'>&times;</span>
  <p></p>
 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Gracias @Dev.Joel , tiene algunos errores, como que se para cuando quedan 2 segundos y luego si tocas de nuevo el botón se ve que sigue la cuenta, y sigue ascendente pero con el signo de menos delante. A ver si contu propuesta puedo hacerlo mejor y doy tu respuesta por buena.

Comment: @MiguelEspeso revisar mi actualización, no me fije algunos detalles y también está solucionado para que siempre inicie en 5 el conteo. Saludos y comenta si tienes dudas o algo se me escapó

Comment: Gracias  @Dev. Joel por la nueva forma de hacerlo, es interesante.